# check the data and return the wanted value

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have two columns of phone number and landline some have only phone number and some have only landline and some have both . I need to make new column and it will check both columns and it will return mobile or landline or both.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your pandas.DataFrame is called `df`, `mobile` and `landline` columns contain phone numbers. I would write a function that checks if a column has a value or not, and then apply it to the dataframe row-wise like this:

```
# You may discard type annotations if you want.
def phone_type(row: dict) -> str:
    # It is not obligatory to coerce to boolean
    has_mobile = bool(row["mobile"]) 
    has_landline = bool(row["landline"])

    if has_mobile and has_landline:
        return "both"
    elif has_mobile:
        return "mobile"
    elif has_landline:
        return "landline"
    else:
        return "no phone"

df["phone_type"] = df.apply(phone_type, axis=1)
```

`df.apply(function, axis=1)` treats each row as a `dict`, so we can access the columns as dictionary keys.